# UI Button in Unity 3d Not Working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I followed an AR Tutorial that uses a UI Button but after I followed it, created the button in a script and ran it, the button didn't work. I don't know why, I followed the tutorial correctly.

[image]

This is the link to the Tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aE_WjB2urM&t=1027s

This is the script I got from the tutorial:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class UserInterfaceButtons : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float scalingSpeed = 0.03f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 70.0f;
    public float translationSpeed = 5.0f;
//  public GameObject Model;
    bool repeatScaleUp = false;
    bool repeatScaleDown = false;
    bool repeatRotateLeft = false;
    bool repeatRotateRight = false;
    bool repeatPositionUp = false;
    bool repeatPositionDown = false;
    bool repeatPositionLeft = false;
    bool repeatPositionRight = false;

    void Update ()
    {
        if (repeatScaleUp) {
            ScaleUpButton ();
        }

        if (repeatScaleDown) {
            ScaleDownButton ();
        }

        if (repeatRotateRight) {
            RotationRightButton();
        }

        if (repeatRotateLeft) {
            RotationLeftButton();
        }

        if (repeatPositionUp) {
            PositionUpButton();
        }

        if (repeatPositionDown) {
            PositionDownButton();
        }

        if (repeatPositionLeft) {
            PositionLeftButton();
        }

        if (repeatPositionRight) {
            PositionRightButton();
        }

    }

    public void CloseAppButton ()
    {
        Application.Quit ();
    }

    public void RotationRightButton ()
    {
        // transform.Rotate (0, -rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        GameObject.FindWithTag ("Model").transform.Rotate (0, -rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }

    public void RotationLeftButton ()
    {
        // transform.Rotate (0, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        GameObject.FindWithTag ("Model").transform.Rotate (0, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }

    public void RotationRightButtonRepeat ()
    {
        // transform.Rotate (0, -rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        repeatRotateRight=true;
    }

    public void RotationLeftButtonRepeat ()
    {
        // transform.Rotate (0, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        repeatRotateLeft=true;
    }

    public void ScaleUpButton ()
    {
        // transform.localScale += new Vector3(scalingSpeed, scalingSpeed, scalingSpeed);
            GameObject.FindWithTag ("Model").transform.localScale += new Vector3 (scalingSpeed, scalingSpeed, scalingSpeed);
        }

    public void ScaleUpButtonRepeat ()
    {
        repeatScaleUp = true;
        Debug.Log ("Up");
    }
    public void ScaleDownButtonRepeat ()
    {
        repeatScaleDown = true;
        Debug.Log ("Down");
    }
    public void PositionDownButtonRepeat ()
    {
        repeatPositionDown = true;
    }
    public void PositionUpButtonRepeat ()
    {
        repeatPositionUp = true;
    }
    public void PositionLeftButtonRepeat ()
    {
        repeatPositionLeft = true;
    }
    public void PositionRightButtonRepeat ()
    {
        repeatPositionRight = true;
    }

    public void ScaleUpButtonOff ()
    {
        repeatScaleUp = false;
        Debug.Log ("Off");
    }
    public void ScaleDownButtonOff ()
    {
        repeatScaleDown = false;
        Debug.Log ("Off");
    }

    public void RotateLeftButtonOff ()
    {
        repeatRotateLeft = false;
        Debug.Log ("Off");
    }

    public void RotateRightButtonOff ()
    {
        repeatRotateRight = false;
        Debug.Log ("Off");
    }
    public void PositionRightButtonOff ()
    {
        repeatPositionRight = false;
        Debug.Log ("Off");
    }
    public void PositionLeftButtonOff ()
    {
        repeatPositionLeft = false;
        Debug.Log ("Off");
    }
    public void PositionUpButtonOff ()
    {
        repeatPositionUp = false;
        Debug.Log ("Off");
    }
    public void PositionDownButtonOff ()
    {
        repeatPositionDown = false;
        Debug.Log ("Off");
    }

    public void ScaleDownButton ()
    {
        // transform.localScale += new Vector3(-scalingSpeed, -scalingSpeed, -scalingSpeed);
        GameObject.FindWithTag ("Model").transform.localScale += new Vector3 (-scalingSpeed, -scalingSpeed, -scalingSpeed);
    }

    public void PositionUpButton ()
    {
        GameObject.FindWithTag ("Model").transform.Translate (0, 0, -translationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    public void PositionDownButton ()
    {

        GameObject.FindWithTag ("Model").transform.Translate (0, 0, translationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    public void PositionRightButton ()
    {
        GameObject.FindWithTag ("Model").transform.Translate (-translationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }

    public void PositionLeftButton ()
    {
        GameObject.FindWithTag ("Model").transform.Translate (translationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);  // backward
    }

    public void ChangeScene (string a)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel (a);
    }

    public void AnyButton ()
    {
        Debug.Log ("Any");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you selected the desired method on the Button `OnClick` event or on the Event Trigger `OnPointerUp / OnPointerDown`?

Comment: One possible problem if an image obstruct a button then button will not work you have to uncheck ignore raycast option for that image or make sure that image should not cover/obstruct the button.